# apt-get install fails due to dependent packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have an offline machine M1 and online machine M2. M1 has only access to a local repository in an intranet. Apparently it has lots of lacking packages. So I wanted to install all the program in M2 to M1. I have read about apt-offline but I was not able to install some basic programs, vim for example. So as I encounter, I have copied all the .deb files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` from M2 to M1 and put into same path and depackaged them all. Now when I try to call apt-get install someProgram, my machine says `"The following packages have unmet dependencies: someAnotherProgram"`. How could I erase these packages which have unmet dependencies?

Comment: does this work?  `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I had tried apt-get purge which did not helped, but your solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix broken dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```